# flag for migration is absent

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

Why I don't see anymore flag for migration? I remember I saw it before.

[image]

If you choose: *it should be closed for another reason..* , you get the following options:

[image]

You don't have migration here, not clear why I should choose off-topic.

Comment: Take a look under "it should be closed for another reason..." then pick "off topic because..."

Comment: but if I don't think it should be closed, but just migrated to another site?

Comment: If the post is migrated, the question is 'closed' on the site it was migrated away from since it is assumed it is off topic.

Comment: I guess by now you can only close the question, or add a generic description.

Comment: I'm afraid I also was confused by the lack of a "migration" flag, and did't have pick "close ... off topic" either. Like Alex, I don't want to close the question - it's a good question, but belongs somewhere else. Luckily, I'm procrastinating and came here, otherwise my flag would not have been made...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The flag reason you're looking for is under `Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration`.

[image: Flag menu]
[image: Close menu]
[image: Off-Topic menu]

The migration menu includes the site's meta and the top four sites for migration from that particular site. For Stack Overflow, they are [Super User](//superuser.com), [TeX.SE](//tex.stackexchange.com), [Database Administrators](//dba.stackexchange.com), and [SharePoint.SE](//sharepoint.stackexchange.com).

[image: Migration sites]

If the question belongs on a site other than those, and ***it is on-topic there and well-written***, you may flag it with a custom flag for moderator attention with a message that includes the site it should be migrated to.

Comment: @Joe I would have, but I knew that if I went over the lines, you wouldn't be able to read the descriptions for each menu.