# How can I move a question between Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions, moderation

Today I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/838355/can-i-safely-mix-ram-ecc-sizes-in-a-server-board) in the SuperUser site. Later, I realized it could be a better fit for ServerFault. I don't want to duplicate the question and ask it again there. Is there a way for me, a regular user with no mod powers, to move the question from SuperUser to ServerFault?

If not, can I request it to someone or somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: I don't think it's a dup, but [here is an answer that points out where the flag for this is.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267416/2607247) At the same time, I believe this question should be on MSE as it's not about Stack Overflow. (Don't quote me on that, I could very well be wrong and it be welcome here.)

Comment: @Kendra - you're right. This question isn't about SO or a wider, general network issue, but about Super User and Server Fault. It's off topic here.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks, I thought so but I wasn't 100% on that. Francisco, [here's a post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) that explains migration, and how it works. Note this part: _"Don't migrate for the sake of migration. We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on the original site."_ So if the question is on-topic on SuperUser, it's extremely unlikely to get migrated.

Comment: `This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange`. This is about the SE software.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is.  Here's how to do it:

> Delete the question on the originating site, and re-post it to the correct site.

That's it.

Comment: But then you could lose rep and stuff for deleting it.

Comment: @ArchieBaer: Cross-posting is discouraged anyway.